# how to get attendances Track from the Google API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-meet

We are using the API of google calendar to create events and we have some invites to that, the problem is that we want to get the Attendance, we know that calendar has the feature [Attendance Tracking](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/10090454?hl=en), and that works perfectly, but we need to get that information from the google API. for now it sends me a email at the end of the meet with an excel with that information. but I need to get it from the API cos, we have a lot of meeting and need to update this information automaticly.

thanks a lot if you give some route or some idea to reach it!!!

I am triging to get this information from the caelndar API V3 following [this doc](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get) but I just get the event info and attendees, but I need to get the Attendance.

Comment: I notice that you can get more details using event.get and check the status of confirmed, however that does not confirm if that person attended, do you have a sample code of what you have done?

Comment: I am using the request `/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId` following this doc https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get but it doesn't return the attendance.

Comment: Attendance Tracking is not generally available. It's only available only for some Google Workspace editions. Are you using Google Workspace accounts? What edition are you using?